# Why does GitAhead give this error on fetch/pull?

Tags: gitahead

I am using GitAhead on an existing repo, and trying to pull or fetch to get updates.

GitAhead is giving me this error:

`Unable to fetch from 'origin' - config value 'autoupdate.enable' was not found`

Git itself doesn't seem to have this config parameter .. so not sure what GitAhead is expecting.

Appreciate any pointers/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [config parameter of GitAhead](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/search?q=autoupdate&unscoped_q=autoupdate) so it might be an internal bug. Does it happen with the latest version of GitAhead / any existing git repository?

The developer might help you / fix the bug if you [raise an issue](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues).

Comment: Maybe issue specific to amazon web services codecommit via ssh, as they rely on ~/.ssh/config User value of aws "SSH key ID" .. [raised issue](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/271)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using GitAhead for a while, but mainly for viewing the merge graphs. I just tried using GitAhead to do a pull, and I ran into this problem as well.

I couldn't find any solutions online, but I found that GitAhead (version 2.62.2 on CentOS 7.8) does not understand:

```
ssh://hostname/path_to_repo
```

I get the error in the original question.

However, the solution for me was to use the following URL when cloning from a remote repository:

```sh
git clone user_id@hostname:/path_to_repo
```

After creating another clone with this URL, I'm able to pull in GitAhead.